# NextJS - function passed as a prop not called onClick

Tags: next.js

Good day. I've created a NextJS app and in the app page I've called a component I've created called ButtonComponent. The component has a prop called "buttonClick" that is passed into the onClick handler of the  inside the component. Then I've passed a function with a console log from the app page into the ButtonComponent as a prop. However on clicking the button, the console log from the app page is not being displayed.

note - I've passed the function inside another function in the ButtonComponent to make sure theonClick is being triggered. The code is as below.

**app page**

```
import React from "react";

import "./homePage.css";

import ButtonComponent from "@/Components/ButtonComponent/ButtonComponent";

const Home = () => {
  const buttonClick = async () => {
    "use server";
    console.log("Function from the App Page");
  };

  return (
    <main className="homepage">
      <div>
        <ButtonComponent
          className={"sales-button"}
          label={"Sales"}
          buttonClick={buttonClick}
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**ButtonComponent**

```
"use client";
import React from "react";

import "./buttonComponent.css";

const ButtonComponent = ({
  label = "Button",
  buttonClick,
  className = "button",
}: any) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Check to see if onClick is triggering");
    buttonClick();
  };
  return (
    <button className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonComponent;
```

I'm new to NextJS and none of the docs or questions I looked up showed a solution for this particular problem.

I did try passing an array to see if props are being passed and evidently they are. Its just the function not being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in the ButtonComponent, inside the handleClick function you meant to call the function buttonClick but instead, you just referenced it without invoking it. To call the function you include the parentheses after the function name. Ideally, the handle click function should look like this:

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Check to see if onClick is triggering");
    buttonClick();
    };
```